# Sqoop JDBC connection timeout after import but before hive import

Tags: hadoop, sqoop

We are using Sqoop v1.4.4

```
14/05/27 13:49:14 INFO sqoop.Sqoop: Running Sqoop version: 1.4.4-cdh5.0.0
Sqoop 1.4.4-cdh5.0.0
git commit id 8e266e052e423af592871e2dfe09d54c03f6a0e8
```

When I'm importing a table from Oracle which takes more than 1 hour to extract, I'm getting following error message at the stage when Sqoop tries to import data from temporary HDFS location into Hive:

```
14/05/27 13:05:51 INFO mapreduce.ImportJobBase: Transferred 47.2606 GB in 6,389.4644 seconds (6.7206 MB/sec)
14/05/27 13:05:51 INFO mapreduce.ImportJobBase: Retrieved 98235461 records.
14/05/27 13:05:51 DEBUG util.ClassLoaderStack: Restoring classloader: sun.misc.Launcher$AppClassLoader@566d0085
14/05/27 13:05:51 DEBUG hive.HiveImport: Hive.inputTable: WAREHOUSE.MY_BIG_TABLE
14/05/27 13:05:51 DEBUG hive.HiveImport: Hive.outputTable: WAREHOUSE.MY_BIG_TABLE
14/05/27 13:05:51 DEBUG manager.OracleManager: Using column names query: SELECT t.* FROM WAREHOUSE.MY_BIG_TABLE t WHERE 1=0
14/05/27 13:05:51 DEBUG manager.SqlManager: Execute getColumnTypesRawQuery : SELECT t.* FROM WAREHOUSE.MY_BIG_TABLE t WHERE 1=0
14/05/27 13:05:51 ERROR manager.SqlManager: Error executing statement: java.sql.SQLException: ORA-02396: exceeded maximum idle time, please connect again

java.sql.SQLException: ORA-02396: exceeded maximum idle time, please connect again

    at oracle.jdbc.driver.T4CTTIoer.processError(T4CTTIoer.java:447)
    at oracle.jdbc.driver.T4CTTIoer.processError(T4CTTIoer.java:389)
```

With small tables (under 1 hour) everything is fine.

This problem looks **exactly** as described in this [SQOOP-934](https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/SQOOP-934) issue, and it was fixed in version 1.4.4, but as I said we are using v1.4.4

Do you know how to solve this problem?

Comment: Welcome to Super User. Please take a minute to read [ask], then [edit] your question to be more clear as what you are asking. As it stands, it is difficult to understand what you are asking (because you haven't asked a question).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This problem was fixed ([SQOOP-1329](https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/SQOOP-1329)) in Sqoop version 1.4.5